# postgresql function not found

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, commit

Trying to run sha256 function

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sha256(bytea) returns text AS $$
    SELECT encode(digest($1, 'sha256'), 'hex')
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT IMMUTABLE;

WITH
tab_email as        (SELECT 'my@email.com'::text as email FROM tmp),
INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ((SELECT email FROM tab_email), sha256('mypass'));
```

i got this error

> ERROR:  function sha256(text) does not exist

Comment: `INSERT INTO users SELECT email, sha256('mypass') FROM tab_email;`

Comment: @lad2025 That's better, but does not explain the error. Which is odd.

Comment: What does `\df *.sha256` show? How about `SELECT sha256('1')` ?

Answer (score 7):

It's because Postgres's built-in `sha256` function takes a `bytea` argument:

```
citus=> \df+ sha256
                                                                               List of functions
   Schema   |  Name  | Result data type | Argument data types | Type | Volatility | Parallel |  Owner   | Security | Access privileges | Language | Source code  | Description
------------+--------+------------------+---------------------+------+------------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+--------------+--------------
 pg_catalog | sha256 | bytea            | bytea               | func | immutable  | safe     | postgres | invoker  |                   | internal | sha256_bytea | SHA-256 hash
(1 row)
```

So just cast to `::bytea` first.

```
citus=> select encode(sha256('a'::bytea), 'hex');
                              encode
------------------------------------------------------------------
 ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
encode(digest(password, 'sha256'), 'hex') from tab_password)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you create this function in redshift, you will be able to your f_sha256

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sha256 (mes VARCHAR)
    returns VARCHAR
    STABLE AS $$
    import hashlib
    return hashlib.sha256(mes).hexdigest()
    $$ language plpythonu;
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.